# How to change value of an element inside a Javascript map() function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapreduce

I have a snippet that queries a database and returns a collection of user objects:

```
users: () => User
      .find()
      .then(users => users.map(user => user._doc))
      .catch((err) => { throw err; }),
```

As apparent, each user object consists of fields, such as username, firstName, password, etc. However, I'd like to assign `null` to the password field before returning the object (`user._doc`). For this, I tried the following:

```
.then(users => users.map(user => { ...user._doc, password: null }))
```

But it failed with a syntax error. Any help?

Example data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "_id": "5c8664161b81d506e5c98e98",
        "firstName": "Bill",
        "password": "$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$m57TfbtPVGS5xnJ6PORO9A$G4cvgac/wdtnra0+st+VWTplFNL+6B5zCrGovdWh7jOGAc2el9kVRg",
        "username": "gates",
        "apiKey": "5c8664161b81d506e5c98e97",
        "privileges": [
          "GUEST",
          "AUTHOR",
          "EDITOR"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c8666e132dfae0802bb855b",
        "firstName": "Jim",
        "password": "$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$TGImmObOvhKN4L/gYHMnsg$6ymjG5iwXCgKkm5VL+jJs5qyqDKsMpSL3oJbg4sJaDHk1z+v1jtVQA",
        "username": "jimm",
        "apiKey": "5c8666e132dfae0802bb855a",
        "privileges": [
          "GUEST",
          "AUTHOR",
          "EDITOR"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c873f9fd925640b0460e23b",
        "firstName": "Tom",
        "password": "$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$IHIUzO7eFjzVSxJa1aeIsQ$Z2LkCnBZCSutTTq0WLmF8KB8p/HJsvuPP2JnaVwzoYLyVh9/9bh6EA",
        "username": "tom",
        "apiKey": "5c873f9fd925640b0460e23a",
        "privileges": [
          "OWNER"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the example data?

Comment: Don't think `user =>enter code here {` is valid syntax either, but you need to surround the object in parentheses

Comment: to use arrow function you can do 
.then(users => users.map(user => ({ ...user._doc, password: null })))

Comment: Hi try this,   users: () => User
      .find()
      .then(users => users.map(user =>  Object.assgin({ password: null }, user._doc)))
      .catch((err) => { throw err; }),

Comment: @Eftakhar, could you please post it as an answer so I could accept and close? Yours is the simplest solution by far!

Comment: @TheLeaner, the option to post the answer is not present for me as your question is marked as duplicate.